# MR job to append strings to long lines according to a key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My data:

```
ABC|value x|value y
CDE|value n|value m
GHI|value h|value i
ABC|value o|value p
CDE|value f|value g
```

I need this output:

```
ABC: (value x, value y), (value o, value p)
CDE: (value n, value m), (value f, value g)
GHI: (value h, value i)
```

My understanding is that at the mapper I should split the input into key-value pairs like this:

```
"value x|value y"             ABC
"value n|value m"             CDE
```

But I am stuck at the reducer -- any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.

The mapper should actually produce this:

```
ABC             "value x|value y"             
CDE             "value n|value m"
```

And then, in the reducer -- knowing that Hadoop by default sorts keys -- we can use simple logic of adding subsequent values to a key `if key == next key`.